# MySql >= 5.5 - INSERT INTO .... { SELECT .... } ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates, insert-into

I have to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a1, lot1, of1, fields1)
  SELECT a2, lot2, of2, fields2
  FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  a1 = a2,
  lot1 = lot2,
  of1 = of2,
  fields1 = fields2
```

I know that with MySql >= 5.5 you have to list all the fields you want to update and there is no syntactic sugar to do this (I cannot use REPLACE INTO, the deletion will break things since I have got a auto increment key column).

Has anyone found a nice solution that will avoid to list all the fields?